How to remove markdown code in email where result came from Gemini
I have an app that is showing data from Google Gemini. To maintain the formatting from the Gemini response, I am using LocalizedStringKey. This way, when Gemini wants to display text in Bold, it does so successfully.
However, when I try to send an email with the text results from Gemini, I get all kinds of additional code in email text. Wondering how to strip that code so it is easier to read.
See these images:
Working as expected.
Not working as expected in the email body.
@State private var response: LocalizedStringKey = "**Hello, I'm Annabelle!**\n\nHow can I help answer your landscape, gardening or plant question today?"

.sheet(isPresented: $isShowingMailView) {
    MailView(result: $result) { composer in
        composer.setSubject("PlantGenie Result")
        composer.setToRecipients([""])
        
        composer.setMessageBody("Annebelle found the following answer:\n\n\(response))", isHTML: false)
        
    }
    
    Task {
        do {
            let generatedResponse = try await model.generateContent(textInput)
            
            guard let text = generatedResponse.text else  {
                textInput = "Sorry, Gemini got some problems.\nPlease try again later."
                return
            }
            textInput = ""
            response = LocalizedStringKey(text)
            isThinking.toggle()
        } catch {
            response = "Something went wrong!\n\(error.localizedDescription)"
        }
    }
}

I can get by without using LocalizedStringKey, but the result shown from Gemini displays the markdown code, but it is somewhat easier to read in the email body.
See these images:
Gemini shows markdown code.
Easier to read in email.
So, I would like to use LocalizedStringKey, so Gemini formats the result AND have the email body read easy on the eyes, so would need to figure out how to strip out the code in the resulting email body.
Any ideas?

Why don't you just store the response as a simple String? Convert it to LocalizedStringKey only when you want to display it in a Text, and send the String in the email.
